# graphql-subscriptions withFilter returns undefined; subscriptions without variables work ok

Tags: graphql, graphql-js, graphql-subscriptions

I'm trying to get my head around graphql-subscriptions and withFilter. Subscriptions without variables work as intended, but if I try to use withFilter, I only get 'Subscription field must return Async Iterable. Received: undefined' error when I try to run the subscription.

Am I doing something wrong with setting up withFilter, are the some incompatibilities with packages I'm using or am I completely missing something obvious here? All queries and mutations work properly, so the basic set up should be fine.

My set up is similar to this (all code snippets are in https://gist.github.com/aqmattil/41e10e7c9f30b8ea964cecdc61c58f20

Package.json

```
// package.json
"dependencies": {
    "apollo-server-express": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "express": "^4.16.3",
    "graphql": "^0.13.2",
    "graphql-subscriptions": "^0.5.8",
    "subscriptions-transport-ws": "^0.9.11"
  }
```

Mutations

```
// mutations.js
const mutation = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'mutation',
fields: {
    addSite: {
        type: SiteType,
        description: "Create a new Site",
        args: {
            name: { type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString) },
            location: { type: GraphQLString },
            company: { type: GraphQLString }
        },
        async resolve(parentValue, { name, location, company }) {
            const site = await new Site({ name, location, company }).save()
            const siteid = site._id;
            console.log("addSite resolve", siteid, name, location, company );
            pubsub.publish('siteAdded', { 'siteAdded': site } );
            return site;
        }
    }
    }
});
module.exports = mutation;
```

Subscriptions

```
// subscriptions.js
const graphql = require('graphql');
const {
    GraphQLObjectType,
    GraphQLString
} = graphql;
const { withFilter } = require('graphql-subscriptions');

const SiteType = require('./site_type');
const pubsub = require('./pubsub_helper');

const Subscriptions = new GraphQLObjectType({
name: 'subscription',
fields: () => ({
/* 
    // this code works, commented out to test withfilter
    siteAdded: {
        type: SiteType,
        resolve(payload) {
            return payload.siteAdded;
        },
        subscribe() {
            return pubsub.asyncIterator('siteAdded');
        }
    },
 */
    // test withFilter
    siteAdded: {
        type: SiteType,
        args: {
            name: { type: GraphQLString }
        },
        resolve(payload) {
            return payload.siteAdded;
        },
        subscribe() {
            // this returns undefined 
            withFilter(
                () => {
                    console.log("in subscribe withfilter");
                    return pubsub.asyncIterator('siteAdded');
                }
            ),
            (payload, variables) => {
                console.log("payload, variables", payload, variables);
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
})
});
module.exports = Subscriptions;
```

I'm using graphiql to run the queries,

```
// this is used to add a site
mutation {
  addSite(name:"test name", location: "somewhere") {
    id
  }
}

// simple subscription -  this works as inteded, and new sites are shown 
subscription {
  siteAdded {
    name
    location
    company {
      id
    }
  }
}

// using query variables --> returns "Subscription 
// field must return Async Iterable. Received: undefined"
subscription {
  siteAdded(name: "test name") {
    name
    location
    company {
      id
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: EDIT: My problem seems to be caused by the nested queries, i.e. Site looks for a Company in the schema. If the nesting is removed, subscriptions and withFilter work properly. 

I had to change the type definitions and resolvers and use makeExecutableSchema as well, but now my example seems to work. 

I updated the gist with a runnable example. Still need to figure out how to get the nested queries working.